# Why isn't my sprintf working in matlab?

Tags: matlab, printf

I am completely new to programming and have no idea what I am doing.  I have been stuck all day trying to get an sprintf command to work.  If I understand correctly, I need to initialize the file I want it to write to, like so:

```
recalltest = strcat('DRMRecall_',num2str(subNo),'.log');
fopen(recalltest, 'wt');
if recalltest == -1
    error('Error opening log file');
end
```

Then, define the variable I'd like written to the file:

```
    recall1 = GetEchoString(w, 'List 1: ', 20, 800, 1);
```

And then I try to write that variable to my log file:

```
sprintf(recalltest, '%s,', recall1);
fclose('all');
```

There is a bunch of stuff in between each of those, but I am hoping these are all the relevant parts.  The log file gets created, but no matter what I do I can't get anything written to it.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

[`sprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sprintf.html) formats data into a string; I'm surprised that code runs at all. You want [`fprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fprintf.html) to output to a file.

Comment: Nothing changes when I use fprintf instead.

Answer (score 1):

Some fixes to the code:

% tested code.

```
recalltest = strcat('DRMRecall_',num2str(subNo),'.log');
FileID = fopen(recalltest, 'wt');
if FileID == -1
    error('Error opening log file');
end
```

% tested code ends.

% Here goes your `GetEchoString` function call. If this code fails, the reason is probably in this function call or in the function itself.

% not tested code.

```
recall1 = GetEchoString(w, 'List 1: ', 20, 800, 1);
```

% not tested code ends.

You had `'%s,'` in your `fprintf` call, which prints `,` after the string `recall1`.
If this is your purpose, put `,` back on the next code line. But you can also add it to `recall1` by using `strcat` before printing.

% tested code.

```
fprintf(FileID, '%s', recall1);
fclose(FileID);
```

% tested code ends.

Normally you can use `fprintf` for all printing, both to files and to screen. To print to a file, the first argument in `fprintf` function call must be `FileID`, which is commonly called `fid` in MATLAB documentation and elsewhere. `FileID` or `fid` is not the name of the file, it's just a number returned by `fopen`, and it's only valid between `fopen` and the relevant `fclose`. It's not a constant related to a specific file or file content, so you must store the returned value of `fopen` always to be able to read from or write to the file.

`sprintf` doesnt't print anything anywhere, neither to the screen nor to any file, it only formats the data into a string, as it says on `sprintf` documentation. `sprintf` output (it's first returned value, the second is `err`) can be printed on screen by using `disp`.

Answer (score 0):

```
recalltest = sprintf('DRMRecall_%d.log', subNo); % usage of sprintf to create a string
fid = fopen(recalltest, 'wt');
assert(fid ~= -1, 'Error opening log file'); % save if...
recall1 = GetEchoString(w, 'List 1: ', 20, 800, 1);
fprintf(fid, '%s\n', recall1); % usage of fprintf to write to a file
fclose(fid);
```